# Declaration of job is incompatible with interface

Tags: php, laravel, azure-web-app-service, declaration, laravel-8

I'm getting a declaration error when I try my newest job. I've built many similar jobs, but I can't seem to find what's wrong with this one that it's getting an error. Please help! I've probably just been staring at it too long. Each file states "use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;" but the carbon class still seems to be unstated.

**This is the error:**

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
> *Declaration of App\Services\Shopify\ShopifyService::getOnlineOrders(App\Services\Shopify\Carbon
> $startDate, App\Services\Shopify\Carbon $endDate) must be compatible
> with
> App\Services\Shopify\ShopifyServiceInterface::getOnlineOrders(Illuminate\Support\Carbon
> $startDate, Illuminate\Support\Carbon $endDate)*

**This is the job:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Testing;

use App\Models\OnlineOrder;
use App\Services\Shopify\ShopifyService;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Carbon\Carbon as MexicanJoe;
use function json_encode;
use function app;

use Exception;

class OnlineOrderSyncJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $startDate;
    protected $endDate;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param Carbon $startDate
     * @param Carbon $endDate
     */
    public function __construct(Carbon $startDate, Carbon $endDate)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
        $this->endDate = $endDate;
    }


    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // get all the created and updated orders
        $orders = app(ShopifyService::class)->getOnlineOrders($this->startDate, $this->endDate);

        Log::channel('dataSync')->info("Complete: OnlineOrderSyncJob", [
            'startDate' => $this->startDate->toDateTimeLocalString(),
            'endDate' => $this->endDate->toDateTimeLocalString(),
            'Orders' => $orders
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     *
     * @param  Exception $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        Log::channel('dataSync')->error('UNABLE TO SYNC ONLINE ORDERS.', [
            'errors' => json_encode($exception->getMessage()),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**This is the service the job is calling:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Shopify;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use function config;
use function json_decode;

class ShopifyService implements ShopifyServiceInterface
{

    /**
     * Get all the conversations created or updated between two dates
     *
     * @param Carbon $startDate
     * @param Carbon $endDate
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOnlineOrders(Carbon $startDate, Carbon $endDate)
    {

        $response = Http::withBasicAuth('[secret stuff]', '[more secret stuff]')->
                        get('https://[secret stuff]:[more secret stuff].myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/orders.json', [
                        'created_at_min' => $startDate->toDateTimeLocalString(),
                        'updated_at_max' => $endDate->toDateTimeLocalString(),
                            ]);

        $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody());

        return $responseData;
    }

}
```

**This is the interface:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Shopify;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

interface ShopifyServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * Get all the audits modified between two dates
     *
     * @param Carbon $startDate
     * @param Carbon $endDate
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOnlineOrders(Carbon $startDate, Carbon $endDate);
    
}
```

Comment: You're not importing the `Carbon` class. It's right there in the error message `App\Services\Shopify\Carbon $startDate`

Comment: But I am (I think) because each file has "use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;" stated, same as all my other jobs which use this structure. Which is why I'm confused

Comment: based on what you have here you should not get that error ... is that an old error before you imported/aliased Carbon in that file?

Comment: Well it's also got `>php?` in line one, so clearly not a copy/paste from live code ;)

Comment: @miken32 hahah correct, I type too fast for my own good, that is not in the file.

Comment: @lagbox it's a current error, i've run cache clears and restarted the queues and still it persists

Comment: `App\Services\Shopify\Carbon` this means `Carbon` isn't aliased/imported in that Service class file ... though your code has it ... have you restarted the Queue workers after making changes to these files? as they don't pick up changes since the queue workers are a long running process in daemon mode

Comment: @lagbox I have, but i've just flushed, optimized, and restarted them again after remove the unused carbon class and apparently that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the aliased carbon class, flushing the queue, running php artisan optimize, and then restarting the queue again. I believe my alias was causing trouble, I've used it elsewhere without issue and will investigate what went wrong here but it's now functioning. Thanks!